# Странное поведение background (вероятно на ретина-экранах)

Tags: css, css3, изображения, svg

Собственно столкнулся с проблемой на сайте - появлением тонких горизонтальных полос на планшете/телефоне (вероятно на ретина-экранах). Подскажите, как от этого проще всего избавиться?

Чтобы пример заработал, увеличьте масштаб до 200% ctrl+Колёсико мыши в хроме.

```css
.head {
  background-color:red;
}
.body {
   padding: 15px 5px;
 background: url('http://geassnovels.ru/images/cutheader.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('/images/cutfooter.png') repeat-x bottom;
 flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-background-size: 11px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class='head'>
 Hello
</div>
<div class='body'>

</div>
```